# Extracting information from netcdf file

Tags: qgis, shapefile, netcdf

I started using QGIS yesterday.

I want to extract the information on GCP from this netCDF file, so that I can perform geospatial analysis: http://dataservices.gfz-potsdam.de/pik/showshort.php?id=escidoc:2740907 (download button is in the top left)

I have only experience working with shapefiles, which is why I would prefer to transform it to shapefile format. However, I would also be happy with a text file featuring xy values and 26 additional columns for the GCP values (the data features GCP per cell from 1850 to 2100 for each decade -> 26 decades).

How do I do either with QGIS?

The dataset is huge and QGIS needs ages just to load it. I would not mind working with a slightly lower resolution, if that would make it easier to handle.

Comment: The usual workflow with huge files is to use gdal_translate on the command line to extract bands, since that does not require the RAM that the QGIS GUI occupies.